# Composer require league/commonmark could not be resolved to an installable set of package fzaninotto/faker

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Problem 1
- fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
- fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.17) does not satisfy that requirement.

How to fix it?[image: Installation failed, reverting./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content]

I try to remove vendor/fzaninotto/faker and the notif like this[image: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with the --ignore-platform-reqs. I like to avoid setting an alias and have it work on composer config level. I Hope it will work.

```
composer require league/commonmark:^2.2 --ignore-platform-reqs.
```